# Mysql - how do I see from which column match came?

Tags: mysql, sql

Examine this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.name_surname, u.avatar, u.location
FROM users AS u
  JOIN connections AS c ON c.user_id = u.id
  JOIN words_en AS w ON w.id = c.word_id
WHERE (w.word = :kwd
  OR u.location = :kwd
  OR u.name_surname = :kwd)
AND u.privacy > 0
AND c.deleted <> 1
```

Is it possible to grab information from where match came? words, location or name? Like an extra column that says the name of the column from which match came?

Comment: You could repeat the condition as a case statement in the select list but do you need to consider if more then one criteria matched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  u.name_surname,
  u.avatar,
  u.location,
  CONCAT_WS(',',
    CASE WHEN w.word = :kwd THEN 'word' END,
    CASE WHEN u.location = :kwd THEN 'location' END,
    CASE WHEN u.name_surname = :kwd THEN 'name_surname' END) As Matches
FROM users AS u
  JOIN connections AS c ON c.user_id = u.id
  JOIN words_en AS w ON w.id = c.word_id
WHERE (w.word = :kwd
  OR u.location = :kwd
  OR u.name_surname = :kwd)
AND u.privacy > 0
AND c.deleted <> 1
```

First CASE WHEN will return 'word' in case that w.word = :kwd or null otherwise, second CASE WHEN will return 'location' if location matches :kwd, third case when will return 'name_surname' if name_surname matches :kwd. I'm then combining in a single column using CONCAT_WS that concatenates the three CASE WHEN, skipping null values.

Please notice that if there are multiple matches, some rows could be duplicated. I would use this select instead:

```
SELECT
  u.name_surname,
  u.avatar,
  u.location,
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT_WS('-',
    CASE WHEN w.word = :kwd THEN 'word' END,
    CASE WHEN u.location = :kwd THEN 'location' END,
    CASE WHEN u.name_surname = :kwd THEN 'name_surname' END)) As Matches
FROM
  ...your from...
WHERE
  ...your where...
GROUP BY
  u.name_surname,
  u.avatar,
  u.location
```

Please see a simplified example [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/939c2/1).